# How to store the result of an async method in a class property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, request-promise

I'm trying to fetch HTML from a webpage, using a class with a single async method. I use Typescript 3.4.3, request-promise 4.2.4.

```js
import * as rp from 'request-promise';

class HtmlFetcher {

  public uri: string;
  public html: string;

  public constructor(uri: string) {
    this.uri = uri;
  }

  public async fetch() {
    await rp(this.uri).then((html) => {
      this.html = html;
    }).catch((error) => {
      throw new Error('Unable to fetch the HTML page');
    });
  }

}

export { HtmlFetcher };
```

I use following code to test my class with Jest 24.8.0. The address at line 6 is used for the sole purpose of testing, I also tried with different URIs.

```js
import { HtmlFetcher } from './htmlFetcher.service';

describe('Fetch HTML', () => {

  it('should fetch the HTMl at the given link', () => {
    const uri = 'http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm';
    const fetcher = new HtmlFetcher(uri);
    fetcher.fetch();

    expect(fetcher.html).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

I expect the `html` property to contain the HTML string fetched at the given address after the fetch() method has been called. However, the test code fails, and logs that `fetcher.html` is `undefined`. The Typescript, Jest and request-promise docs did not provide any help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not waiting for the `fetch()` to finish before checking

Comment: It's an async function, meaning its result won't be available unless you're in the `.then` of the promise, or await it.

Comment: `fetcher.fetch().then(/* check result in here*/)`

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async

Comment: Or use Jest timer mocks https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to [TKoL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959054/tkol)'s comments, and another look at a doc I already read 50 times, namely: [Jest async testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async). I should've RTFM more carefully...

The test code must be async as well.

```js
import { HtmlFetcher } from './htmlFetcher.service';

describe('Fetch HTML', () => {

  it('should fetch the HTMl at the given link', async () => { // Added async keyword
    const uri = 'http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm';
    const fetcher = new HtmlFetcher(uri);
    await fetcher.fetch(); // Added await keyword

    expect(fetcher.html).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```